# Об пол или о пол?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Столкнулась в тесте со словосочетанием «ударился о пол», до этого *пол* везде встречала исключительно с предлогом *об*. Поискала в Интернете, но так и не нашла, как же правильно говорить: ***о** пол* или ***об** пол*. Или возможны оба варианта?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Возможны оба варианта, но с разным ударением: о пОл и Об пол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианты верны.

◊ Об пол, о пол (бросить, швырнуть и т.п.) — с ударом о землю, о пол. — Михайло Степанович подошел к сыну, схватил за руку и дернул его с такою силой, что он грянулся об пол. Герцен.

http://www.frazeologiya.ru/fraza/pol_1.htm

Правило таково:

•   предлог обо пишется перед некоторыми (весьма немногочисленными) формами местоимений: мне, всё (всём), все (всех, всю, всей), что, что то, что-либо, что-нибудь;

•   предлог об пишется перед словами на гласную, исключая йотированные: объявить об амнистии, поведать об итогах, споткнуться об овцу, напомнить об учебе, рассказать об эмпатии;

•   предлог о пишется перед словами на согласную и йотированные гласные: поныть о работе, помечтать о югах, потрындеть о Европе, подумать о России.

При этом в винительном падеже перед словом на согласную могут использоваться и о, и об. Например, обороты убиться о стену и убиться об стену одинаково корректны и литературны.

Comment: Логичней и естественней говорить о гласных и согласных звуках, а не буквах.

Comment: Это естественно, когда речь о произношении, а я применила слово "пишется", значит, перед буквой, обозначающей звук, а короче - перед гласной. Хотя, конечно, научнее было бы сказать: употребляется предлог о перед согласными звуками, в том числе перед й, входящим в йотированные буквы, но это длинно.

Answer (score 1):

**Приставки О и ОБ** , согласно словарю, могут иметь разные оттенки значения: обычно глаголы с приставкой ОБ имеют **более разговорный и более конкретный характер**, чем глаголы с приставкой О: обежать взглядом, обивать пороги.

**Та же закономерность возможна и для предлогов О и ОБ**. Обычно лицо (или предмет) ненамеренно падает и ударяется о пол или об пол,  о землю или об землю. Ситуация вполне конкретная, поэтому  оба предлога О и ОБ используются одинаково часто.

Но бывают случаи, когда на землю падают специально, например: Вдруг прилетают двенадцать голубиц; **ударились о сыру землю** и обернулись красными девицами. И разные другие истории.

В данном случае сказочные персонажи не ударяются, не разбиваются, а  просто касаются земли (чтобы оборотиться, нужно перевернуться, а это удобно сделать, оттолкнувшись от поверхности). И вот в этих случаях, как правило, используется **предлог О** с переносным значением.