# "О стену" или "Об стену"

Tags: предлоги, выбор-варианта

По правилам вроде бы надо писать **о стену**. Почему тогда в корпусе почти столько же примеров **об стену**? (519 против 342)

Comment: Вы не будете возражать против моей правки, надеюсь?

Comment: Спасибо, перепутал что-то. Теперь поправил.

Comment: В винительном падеже перед словами, начинающимися согласными (кроме форм местоименных слов всё, всю, все, всех, что), употребляются предлоги о и об: споткнулся о порог и об порог; ударился о камень и об камень. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8   https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/65341-kak-pravilno-upotreblyat-predlogi-o--ob-i-obo/

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума! У меня к вам убедительная просьба: пожалуйста, оформляйте свои ответы на поле, предназначенном для ответов. Это соответствует правилам форума.  Мне кажется, что порядок нужен во всем.  У нас прекрасные возможности сделать наш ресурс удобным как для собственной работы, так и для наших гостей, которые заходят к нам за интересующей их информацией. Этим мы выгодно отличаемся от чатов, где каждый в свободном режиме пишет то, что ему нравится,  и так, как ему нравится. Я думаю, что модераторы форума поддержат меня в этом.

Comment: Это неполный ответ, поэтому его и следовало поместить в комментариях, если не хотелось отвечать полностью.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните ваше мнение у модераторов. Если существует такое правило, они подтвердят. Тогда неполные ответы, если нам  НЕ ЗАХОЧЕТСЯ  отвечать полностью, мы будем размещать в комментариях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: **об стену и о стену** (винительный падеж, слово начинается с согласной)

Вопрос № 292528 [http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=обратить+внимание](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Правило употребление предлогов **О – ОБ  – ОБО**

Выбор предлога зависит от того, с какого звука (**гласного или согласного**) начинается последующее слово и в какой **падежной форме** оно употребляется:

1. в **винительном падеже** перед словами, начинающимися **согласными** (кроме форм местоименных слов всё, всю, все, всех, что), употребляются предлоги **о и об:** споткнулся о порог и об порог; ударился о камень и об камень;
2. **в винительном падеже** перед словами, начинающимися **гласными**, употребляется только предлог **об**: споткнулся об острый камень;
3. **в винительном падеже** перед формами местоименных слов *все, всё, всех, всю, что*, а также что-либо, что-нибудь, что-то употребляется предлог **обо**: споткнулся обо все камни; Обо что ты споткнулся?
4. **в предложном падеже** перед словами, начинающимися **согласными** (кроме форм местоименных слов мне, всём, всей, всех), употребляется предлог **о**:  узнал о родственниках, вспомнил о невесте;
5. **в предложном падеже** перед словами, начинающимися гласными, употребляется предлог об: вспоминать об отце; задуматься об учебе;
6. **в предложном падеже** перед формами местоименных слов *мне, всём, всей, всех* употребляется предлог **обо**: узнал обо всех родственниках, вспомнил обо мне.

Однако в художественной литературе возможно: **о всем, о всей, о всех** (Девушка пела в церковном хоре // О всех усталых в чужом краю... А. Блок).

**Примечание.** Нужно обратить внимание, что слова, начинающиеся с букв **е, ё, ю, я,** – это слова, начинающиеся **с согласного звука [j].** Поэтому правильно: дискутировать о Европе, песня о ёлке, вспоминать о юных годах, говорить о «Яндексе» (не об).

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что вопрос не столько про правило, сколько, почему это правило такое странное, что допускает "об" перед согласным звуком? Вот комментарии на этот вопрос я хотел бы увидеть :(

Comment: А что вы думаете об Юллясе, Sharon?

Comment: @user190920 Со стороны очевидно, что Вы совсем не понимаете, о чём спрашивалось в вопросе.

Comment: Ну я немного завуалировал реальную проблему, стояющую за этим вопросом. Но думаю, всем кто пытается "зреть в корень" эта проблема довольно очевидна, безотносительно моих комментариев. Собственно в ответе Sharon она нащупана: " я тоже не ожидала, что везде будет предлагаться чисто фонетическое решение, а о семантике не будут говорить ничего."

Comment: За что спасибо?.. Я спросил, что вы об Юллясе думаете... Это местечко в Финляндии, оно без йота читается.

Comment: Извините, вероятно, а вас неправильно поняла. В этой теме какая-то странная путаница с вежливыми словами "спасибо" и  "пожалуйста" :)

Comment: Какая путаница? Ничего такого не заметил... Можете на мой вопрос ответить-то?

Comment: Не могу, Артем:) Вот правда, ничего больше не знаю, в том числе про йоту, которая не читается. Может, еще кто-нибудь ответит.

Comment: Да не йоту, а йот (звук Й)! Это название "Юлляс" читается без звука Й в начале, [вот так](https://forvo.com/search/Yll%C3%A4s/). Получается, тогда и по-русски его лучше так произносить и говорить "об Юллясе", а не "о Юллясе"? Как вы думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарии

**1. Каков вопрос – таков ответ**

**Вопрос:** По правилам вроде бы надо писать о стену. Почему тогда в корпусе почти столько же примеров об стену? (519 против 342)

**Ответ:**  Но правила допускают для В.п. два варианта. В ответе я излагаю это правило в полном объеме.

**Комментарий к ответу:**  Вы же **понимаете**, что вопрос не столько про правило, сколько, почему это правило такое странное, что допускает "об" перед согласным звуком? Вот комментарии на этот вопрос **я хотел бы увидеть.**

**Что тут можно сказать?** Вот не хотелось мне вчера больше дружить и вообще разговаривать с этим участником, но приходится. **Его «не стандарты во всем» вызывают во мне любопытство.** Откуда ему известно, что я понимаю, а что нет.  А если даже понимаю, то имею право сделать вид, что ничего не понимаю. **Хотел бы он увидеть!** Мог бы «пожалуйста» хотя бы добавить, но не считает это нужным.

С другой стороны, я тоже не ожидала, что везде будет предлагаться **чисто фонетическое решение**, а о семантике не будут говорить  ничего. Вот и мне **стало интересно,** почему правило такое странное.

**2. Краткие тезисы к еще не решенному вопросу**

1. На выбор  О и ОБ влияют два фактора: **фонетический и семантический.**
2. Обычно рассматривается только **фонетический фактор, причем в упрощенном виде** (гласные и согласные), но в действительности влияние фонетики более сложное, оно как раз и проявляется в наличии исключений.

Это к вопросу Артема (А что вы думаете об Юллясе, Sharon?).

Здесь я нашла пока такой материал: [http://rusgram.ru/Предложный_падеж](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

Еськова Н.А. О вариантах предлога о, об, обо // Еськова Н.А. Избранные работы по русистике. М. 2011. С. 297–300.
п. 5 **ЭКСКУРС. Варианты предлога о / об / обо**

В частности, там говорится, что «в XIX в. вариант ОБ перед согласными, ср. об наших, об русских, об висте, **был достаточно употребителен**».

Да и вообще  правило, как и многие другие правила,  можно рассматривать как   **наблюдение** за речевой статистикой, а не  точный **регулятор** речевой деятельности. Наверное, нельзя сказать «что вы думаете об Юле», но можно сказать «что вы думаете об Юллясе  (финском горнолыжном курорте)».

3. **О семантическом факторе** говорится очень мало, хотя  он проявляется явно: при выборе предлога учитывается **падеж** существительного. Но  ведь винительный падеж и предложный изъяснительный имеют разную семантику.
4. **Этот вопрос требует проработки**: хотелось бы, конечно,  найти готовое решение или хотя бы высказать свои версии.

Как это сделать? Можно задать такой вопрос: а почему предлог О обслуживает **два падежа,** что между ними общего? Хотя предлог первообразный, но какое-то обобщенное лексическое значение в нем есть.

**5. Сравним варианты:** удариться  о камень, о дерево  – удариться об стол, об кровать, об стену. Во всех случаях происходит взаимодействие двух предметов,  но предлоги разные. В чем тут дело? Возможно, изъяснительное значение  П.п (то есть полного (или значительного)  охвата предмета действием)  проявляется и в пространственном значении В.п..

6. **Или такой пример:** чтобы в кого-то превратиться, рекомендуется удариться о землю, а не об землю (ударилась лягушка о землю и превратилась в красну девицу).  А ненамеренно можно использовать любой вариант (но «об землю» – разговорный стиль). [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431342/Об-пол-или-о-пол](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431342/%D0%9E%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB)
7. Так что вопрос поставлен, и у вас тоже есть возможность ответить на него: **Почему правило такое странное, что допускает "об" перед согласным звуком?**

Comment: Мне очень интересно ваше мнение по тому вопросу.

Comment: Юлляс от А до Я: карта отелей и зоны катания, склоны и трассы. Яркие фото и видео. Отзывы туристов-горнолыжников об Юллясе.  Артем, кажется,  там все уже выбрано, традиция употребления обозначена. Это иноязычный топоним, там  могут действовать особые правила.  Возможно, на выбор ОБ повлияло произношение  без Й. С другой стороны, вы уверены, что в русском варианте финское произношение сохраняется?  Пишется буква Ю, вроде бы и читаться должна буква Ю.

Comment: Вот и меня интересует, как правильно: должно сохраняться финское произношение в русском или добавляться йот. Я бы хотел, чтобы сохранялось. ;)

Comment: Финские названия  могут  начинаться с букв U-Y, на русском они будут записываться как У - Ю. Произношение в русском языке будет соответственное.  Но в  финском языке y – это средний звук между [у] и [ю], как в слоге [бю]. Мы этот звук в начале слова не произносим, приходится говорить Ю.  Но вы лично можете произносить средний звук, нейотированный, если вам так нравится :)